Binary Crossentropy on KerasTensors not working
I'm trying to implement this VAE in tf/keras and there seems to be something wrong with binary_crossentropy.
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Lambda, Input, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.losses import binary_crossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

...

def build_vae():
    ...

    reconstruction_loss = binary_crossentropy(inputs, outputs) * image_size
    kl_loss = 1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var)
    kl_loss = K.sum(kl_loss, axis=-1)
    kl_loss *= -0.5
    vae_loss = K.mean(reconstruction_loss + kl_loss)

I get an error on the binary_crossentropy line. Having confirmed that inputs and outputs are of type KerasTensor, the traceback states:

ValueError: A KerasTensor cannot be used as input to a TensorFlow function. A KerasTensor is a symbolic placeholder for a shape and dtype, used when constructing Keras Functional models or Keras Functions. You can only use it as input to a Keras layer or a Keras operation (from the namespaces keras.layers and keras.operations).

How is this fixed? Additionally, I'm curious why tensorflow.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy doesn't accept KerasTensors or why it's not considered a Keras function even though it's in the keras library.
I've tried wrapping binary_crossentropy in a keras Layer subclass works for that line, but then all the K functions that follow error out. I'd be surprised if I have to repeat that process for all the K functions used

This needs more context. if you have a function build_vae that presumably "builds" the model, the loss should not be computed inside that function.

You can follow the link to the full code for additional context if that helps. You'll note that loss isn't being computed here, its computational graph is being built

That code is five years old. Tensorflow has changed a lot since then. I suggest you look for more up-to-date tutorials, for example on the official website.
